# Change the order list to spanish in java

Tags: java, url

I'm getting the web page's html to get some information, but it always is in English, I need it in spanish, how can I change the language using a user-agent in java, I'm not really into javascript or jquery.
Code to get the html

```
private String conexion(String lineas) {
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    String content = null;
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = new URL(lineas).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        content = scanner.next();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡Ese link no Existe!!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return content;
}
```

In the page, to change the language is with a list.
[image: Code]

Comment: Seems that by this URL backend is setting the language for user session. Does the site send some cookies when responding this url? If yes, then after visiting this link, you need to send these cookies in further requests.

Answer (score 1):

Using URLConnection you definitely won't be able to make 'clicks' on the returned page. However you have a few options, it all depends on web site capabilities :

1. There's an [Accept-Language](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) Header you can set on the HTTP request you make:

   ```
   connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "es_ES");
   ```
2. The target site probably set some [Cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields) to keep track of the language you've chosen, find it and use it. You can find it e.g. in Chrome with [Developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en) :
   [image]
   Here you can see the `lang` Cookie set to `en`.

   ```
   connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "lang=en");
   ```
3. The language is sometimes accepted as a request parameter

   ```
   new URL(lineas + "?lang=en").openConnection();
   ```